# I cannot run application

Tags: scala, playframework

#### Environment

- java 1.8.0_25
- scala 2.11.4
- sbt 0.13.7

I clicked start button in typesafe.

But not application started.

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=128M; support was removed in 8.0
error: error while loading CharSequence, class file '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar(java/lang/CharSequence.class)' is broken
(bad constant pool tag 18 at byte 10)
Type error in expression
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

Then outputted log like the above.

What should I do?

Comment: What is your java, scala & sbt version ?

Comment: java 1.8.0_25
scala 2.11.4
sbt 0.13.7

Comment: Might this be relevant? https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1783

Comment: Thanks Chris Martin and Altius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited play-project/project/build.propaties

```
...
sbt.version=0.12.2
...
```

to

```
...
sbt.version=0.13.7
...
```

Then application started.